# One page of entire site has invisible elements untill resized or scrolled in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

One of my pages of my site is behaving really weird in IE6.
One element is ignoring its background color and border.
The other element is invisible (textcolor same as foreground color?)

The elements are not always showing this behaviour, but about 50% of the loads without any pattern.
When the browser window is resized or scrolled, or the elements are selected, the lay-out shows up fine all of a suddden.

wtf...

Anybody got an idea how I can even start to debug this?

Comment: IE6 is notorious for weird behaviour

Comment: The plan of making a mum/dad accessible UpgradeYourBrowser page was growing for me the last few days, but now caffeine and this bug just filled me with angry rage (the green kind)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you could have been hit by the hasLayout problem/bug in IE6.
Check out http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it could be the [peekaboo bug](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/peekaboo.html).

Answer (score 0):

Before you do anything you should do these two things:

1. Make sure you have a doc-type
2. validate your HTML and css

Once these two things are done, you'll be in a much better position to distinguish between your mistakes and IE's bugs.